# Check partial match between dictionary keys Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have two dictionaries:

```
D1 = {'1A11':'cat'}
D2 = {'1A2':'collar', 'B2':'dog'}
```

And I would like loop the D1 dictionary and return the key,value in dictionary D2 that match the first part of D1 keys.

For example `('1A2A':'collar')` since `1A11` and `1A2` first parts match regardless of the digits at the end.

Thank you so much,

Comment: How do we know the minimum number of common characters required for a valid match?

Comment: You need to define your criteria for "success" in a partial match.  Then you code those criteria into a function.  Finally, iterate through the keys, calling the function on pairs of keys.  Give it a try; if you get stuck, post your code ... at *that* point, you have a good Stack Overflow question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following:

```py
D1 = {'1A11':'cat'}
D2 = {'1A2':'collar', 'B2':'dog'}

def find_partial_matches(first, second, min_count):
    # You need to store the results in a list at least
    matches = []

    # Go through all keys of first dictionary
    for first_key in first:
        # Go through all pairs of second dictionary
        for second_key, second_value in second.items():
            # Check whether the min_count first characters are equal
            if first_key[0:min_count] == second_key[0:min_count]:
                matches.append((second_key, second_value))

    return matches

# In any cases, you will have to provide a minimum number of
# characters to match
print find_partial_matches(D1, D2, 2)
```

This outputs:

```
[('1A2', 'collar')]
```

**Quick explanation**

I basically have a brute force approach. I iterate over all keys of the first dictionary. For each key, I iterate over each pair `(key, value)` of the second dictionary. I check whether the `min_count` first characters of both keys equal (this is done using `[0:min_count]`, meaning start at index `0` and for `min_count` characters), if so this is a match, which I add to the list of matches. Finally return the list.

You could potentially do better. For instance, the above implementation does not handle duplicates (but I'm sure you can handle it ).